# How to connect to mysql using mysql connector via C# without actually installing the connector

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection, mysql-connector

We have a dot net 2.0 based C# product which uses Mysql as the data storage. When we install the mysql connector 6.3.6 on the XP/Win 7 machine, we are able to connect to the database from the C# code without any issues. But we are facing a problem while connecting to the mysql database when the mysql connector is actually not installed on the machine but is just present in the same directory as the executable. We don't want to install the connector on each and every machine we want the product to run on. We want the connectory dll to be used directly as we use any 3rd party dll (e.g logger) in our code.

Even when we copy the mysql.data.dll into the same directory where the exe is installed, it builds but does not connect to the database.

The error given is

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed
>   Blockquote

Technical Information:

- Mysql 5.0
- C#
- Dot Net framework 2.0
- Mysql Connector 6.3.6 (same problem occurs with ver 6.0.3 of sql connector)
- Win XP/Win 7

When we are using ASP.Net, we can specify the tag given below into the web.config, and we can connect to mysql database directly by putting the dll into the bin directory

---

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=5.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

---

Why can't we do the same thing in the C# for the Client Server application in the desktop environment.

Comment: Do you put the same configuration into the `app.config` of your desktop app?

Comment: We did not put the same configuration in the app.config. The tag DBProviderFactories seems to be invalid in app.config

Comment: This question would have saved me a couple hours of headaches a month ago. All the .Net Connector installation does (from what I understand) is add the "MySQL Data Provider" entry to the machine.config. I did not use the installer and simply added the entry to my config. I was off and running using the .Net ProviderFactories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (I didn't check any possible versions/configurations, but it works currently on my Vista x64 for MySql some 5.5... and .net connector 6.4.3.0 - using mysql.data.dll for v4 from .net/mono download).

Make sure the referenced mysql.data.dll assembly below is in your current directory.

```
using(var dt = new DataTable()) {
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Description");
    dt.Columns.Add("InvariantName");
    dt.Columns.Add("AssemblyQualifiedName");
    dt.Rows.Add("Mysql something", 
        "mysql more", 
        "mysqlClient",
        "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d");

    var f = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dt.Rows[0]);
    using(var conn = f.CreateConnection()) {
        conn.ConnectionString = "your string here";
        conn.Open();
        // and do your work here.
        Console.WriteLine(conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it has worked for me. Is there is drawback in using this method than installing the connector, like in terms of coding, performance or security etc

Comment: No drawback to this method other than you'll have to duplicate mysql.data.dll for all applications that need it. So if you only have one, then this is perfectly fine. In my case there are several so I ended up putting mysql assemblies in GAC and modifying machine.config's in all the right places so I could just use DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("string here I gave in configs") to obtain the factory and go from there. I just like to use those dll's from .net/mono distribution, having to manually set things up as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-installation-windows.html) doesn't go into much detail about .NET Framework dependency, but I suspect that the Mysql connector might be dependent on a later version of the .NET framework.

In other words, your application uses Framework 2, but what version does the Mysql connector use?

Comment: It is compatible with v2 as well as v4 of dot net.

Comment: 6.3.* is compatible with ADO.NET version 2.x+, .NET Framework version 2.x+, 4.x+ for VS 2010 support and MySQL Server version 5.0, 5.1, 5.4, 5.5 as per mysql website

Comment: I am referring the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-versions.html

Comment: It clearly states that the connector work on .net framework 2.0. We even tried the same with version 6.0.3 of the connector but it gives the same error

Comment: i'm having similar problems right now. for some reason the v2.0 assemblies reference v4.0 versions of System.Xaml and others. i suspect some strange and evil GAC magic is at work, the workaround is to compile the .Net connector from source

Answer (score 0):

This entry:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=5.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

... needs to be written into your machine.config.

I believe the default path should be something like:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG

**Update**
You should be able to include MySQL .Net/Connector installer as part of your installation package. The entry in the machine.config is required for the same reasons that information is required in a web.config.

Comment: The people who install the software are not technically sound. So we cant give them to add this entry manually. Is this entry possible via NSIS installer.

Comment: Why this entry is required in the first place would be my question