# my sql provide 6.4.3.0 support for code first entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, ef-code-first

I'm using my sql 6.4.3.0 in server and it returns error:

```
 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.'
```

But in my local, my sql v-6.4.4.0 creating database well, but in my server not creating database. Is that my sql provider supports core first entity framework without database?

**Stack Trace**

```
[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown database 'globaldb']
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +196
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.AuthenticateSSPI() +22
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.AuthenticateNew(Boolean reset) +354
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(Boolean reset) +113
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +1034
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +22
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +218
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +286
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +93
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +65
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +332
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +36
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +26

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +170
   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +40
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +154
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +414
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +17
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +58
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +37
   System.Linq.Queryable.Select(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector) +66
   MyBusinessApp.MvcApplication.InitializeDatabase() in C:\APPS\TestShell\mybusinessapp2\Global.asax.cs:59
   MyBusinessApp.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\APPS\TestShell\mybusinessapp2\Global.asax.cs:53

[HttpException (0x80004005): The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9859725
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +336
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you problem is most likely in the versions of your  my sql 6.4.3.0 version after reading several posts I belive you should update to version sql v-6.4.4.0 the one you use or download the latest version plus it a good idea to keep the local and development as  similar as possible.

Comment: ok but that is in server, so is there any other solution to use the same without upgrading version?

Comment: downgrade it on your local to sql 6.4.3.0 and see if it compiles that the only think i can suggest

Comment: after changing connector in local to 6.4.3.0 getting error:
  at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.get_MySqlDbProviderServicesInstance()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbProviderFactory factory)
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)

Comment: that the same error you got before which means that the connector in local to 6.4.3.0  is not comparable what what you are doing.

Comment: @COLO TOLD 
Yes same error. But we can achieve this without installing 6.4.4.0 but this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395795/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-mysql-connector-via-c-sharp-without-actually-insta 
. But i upgraded to latest version.